# Any way to trigger home button with L Joy-Con only?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I was testing out the Snipperclips demo single player with the L Joy-Con, and I realized that I couldn't get back to the home screen without using the R Joy-Con.

Does anyone know of a way to get to the home screen without using the R Joy-Con, or resetting the console? Perhaps some combo of capture button holding and the L/ZL buttons?

Comment: This is something I noticed myself recently when developing a Switch game.  If the game only supports 1 Joycon, to get back to the home screen, you have to turn the left one off with the Sync button then connect the right Joycon.  I'm tempted to add an "Exit" option to the game for when players are using just 1 Joycon.

Comment: I would recommend supporting 1 controller, but allow it to be a pair like in the charging grip. That way they can turn on the right one at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the only way to reach the Home Menu is by using a Home Button, on a controller which has it.

Same goes for the Share Button when wanting a screen capture.

Comment: I was hoping that if only one was linked the capture button would switch to the home button, but it doesn't seem to work like that. So I guess if you're going to lose a Joy-Con make it the left one!

Answer (score 2):

With the new button mapping system, you can assign the home button function to one of the buttons you normally can't use when your joy-con is in horizontal mode.  I personally use the ZL button on the left joy-con because the L button is much easier to accidentally press when playing a game, and is more sensitive to pressing it down generally.  This way, I still have all of the normal functions of the left controller, but I also have the ability to go home

Comment: Does the mapping system have different settings for different orientations, or would I have to switch that mapping anytime I plan to play with a single joy-con?

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the HOME Menu without the right  joy con. (or pro controller.) Put the console into Sleep Mode then wake it up. Press Featured News. Press Back.

Comment: I also use this method when I'm playing a touch game and leave my Joycon on charge.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings, scroll down to controllers/sensors, click change button mapping, than click change, then remap the capture button to the home button

Answer (score -5):

You can get to the Home Screen without a right joy-con, just **turn the console off and on again**, then by using the console's **touch screen,** tap the **Home Screen icon** (sometimes followed with the text: **'Switch User/Software'**.

Comment: *"Does anyone know of a way to get to the home screen **without using the R Joy-Con, or resetting the console?**"*